# How Do i use array_push in foreach loop PHP?

Tags: php, foreach, array-push

Here is example which I have try

```
<?php
 include 'spider/classes/simple_html_dom.php';
 $html = new simple_html_dom();
 $html->load("<html><body><h2>Heading 1</h2><h2>This heading 2</h2></p></p></body></html>");
 $e = $html->find("h2", 0);
 $key = array();
 if($e->plaintext != ""){
 foreach($html->find("h2", 0) as $e){
    //echo $e->plaintext;
    array_push($key, $e->plaintext);
  }
 } else {
     echo "error";
 }
 print_r($key);
 ?>
```

**Result:**
Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => Heading 1This heading 2

[6] => [7] => )

How Do i use array_push to create an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens, when you try this code?
I removed the first "find" and i also found an example on the internet, where the second param of "find" was not set.

```
<?php
 include 'spider/classes/simple_html_dom.php';
 $html = new simple_html_dom();
 $html->load("<html><body><h2>Heading 1</h2><h2>This heading 2</h2></p></p></body></html>");
 $key = array();
 if(isset($html)){
 foreach($html->find("h2") as $e){
    //echo $e->plaintext;
    array_push($key, $e->plaintext);
  }
 } else {
     echo "error";
 }
 print_r($key);
 ?>
```

Explanation:

```
// Find all anchors, returns a array of element objects
$ret = $html->find('a');

// Find (N)th anchor, returns element object or null if not found (zero based)
$ret = $html->find('a', 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative with the default **DOMDocument** class.

```
$html = new DOMDocument('1.0','utf-8');
$html->loadHTML("<html><body><h2>Heading 1</h2><h2>This heading 2</h2></p></p></body></html>");

$key = array();
$h2 = $html->getElementsByTagName('h2');

for ($i = 0; $i < $h2->length; $i++) {
    array_push($key, $h2->item($i)->nodeValue);
}
print_r($key);
```